# Android initialize firebase databse at very first run

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Anyone can help for a way to create predefined Firebase database for each new authenticated user, basically I want the application to create database with predefined values for every new uid.
I need this to happen only onetime at the very first run of the application.

My application right now is using already structured database by me to run without problems... but after i tried to make my application to create that database instead of me i start receiving Null exception.

This is part of the code and the section where I get error right after I first run the application and before the google sign in message appear or authentication occurred, the application start to read the following section and receive NULL.

```
BluetoothStat.child("BluetoothStat").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            bluetoothStatus.setText(value);

            if (value.equals("ON")){
                bConnect.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bluetooth_on);
                bluetoothBStatus = true;
            }
            else if (value.equals("OFF")){
                bConnect.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bluetooth_off);
                bluetoothBStatus = false;
            }

        }
```

this is what i'm trying to predefine as database for my application

```
userUID = firebaseUser.getUid();

                    Engine = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("Engine");
                    EngineStat = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("EngineStat");
                    Bluetooth = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("Bluetooth");
                    BluetoothStat = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("BluetoothStat");
                    Doors = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("Doors");
                    DoorsStat = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("DoorsStat");
                    HeadLights = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("HeadLights");
                    HeadLightsStat = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("HeadLightsStat");
                    AutoLights = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("AutoLights");
                    AutoLightsStat = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("AutoLightsStat");
                    SystemStat = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("SystemStat");
                    KeyLess = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("KeyLess");
                    ApplicationStat = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("ApplicationStat");
                    ScreenMode = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("ScreenMode");
                    InternetStat = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("InternetStat");
                    Application= myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("Application");


E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.ramir.carhandcontroller, PID: 14759
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ramir.carhandcontroller/com.example.ramir.carhandcontroller.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.ramir.carhandcontroller.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:165)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Can you tell me the value of `BluetoothStat`? And what do you have on the line 165 from your MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer for my Question
The problem with my code that I was trying to refer to Firebase links that didn't exist yet, 
for example

```
Engine = myRef.child("Users").child(userUID).child("Engine");
```

when the code start checking for dataChange of those links (userUID) wasn't created yet, and that was giving NULL exception.

I solved all the mentioned issues by moving my code to another activity, and making Main Activity only to login to Firebase using google sign in method.

During the authentication I will assign user unique code to a String, then at the last stage of sign in I will check if this is the first time my application is running using the following code

```
if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {

                //Initiating Database values can go in here

                prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();

            }
```

after this part I call the other activity using (Intent) with puExtra where I send the userUID.